# Getting "invalid quote formatting for csv" error while copying data from s3 to redshift

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, etl

My csv file uploaded to S3 is having data as below:

```
id,name,post,description,salary
10001,ajay,jr.Engg,"to handle ""cloud related tasks",100000
10002,bimal,sr.engg,"to handle \\db tasks
hello_to_all",200000
10003,chinmay,sr.support,"for deployment """@related activities",250000
10004,dipak,HR,"Resource mngt,Control",300000
10005,Emili,jr.HR,Resource mngt|Control,350000
10006,Falguni,HR,Resource mngt    control,400000
```

I am using below command to copy this data to redshift:

```
copy {table_name}
from 's3_location'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key={secret_access_key}'
csv delimiter ',' quote as '\"' fillrecord blanksasnull IGNOREBLANKLINES emptyasnull acceptinvchars '?' ignoreheader as 1  compupdate off statupdate off truncatecolumns region '{region_name}'
```

I am getting "invalid quote formatting for csv" error for this command but when I use below command

```
copy {table_name}
from 's3_location'
credentials 'aws_access_key_id={access_key};aws_secret_access_key={secret_access_key}'
csv delimiter ',' quote as '^' fillrecord blanksasnull IGNOREBLANKLINES emptyasnull acceptinvchars '?' ignoreheader as 1  compupdate off statupdate off truncatecolumns region '{region_name}'
```

the error changes and the comma (,) present in between the text value for description column gets considered as delimiter and throws error as "Invalid digit, Value 'C', Pos 0, Type: Integer".

Please suggest the correct copy option which will able to copy data from s3 location to redshift.

Answer (score 2):

First off look at stl_load_errors for the copy in question.  This will give the line and the field that has the error.

I suspect the that quoting error is on line starting with 10003.  You have triple double quotes which isn't valid.  Redshift follows rtf 4180 spec for CSV files - https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180 and to achieve a double quote inside a quoted value requires 2 double quotes - Rule 6.

Comment: Thanks @Bill Weiner , But the data is available in this format only, so is pre-processing the data to remove the double quotes is only option to copy data into redshift? Or we have any other conversion parameter to be used in copy option from AWS for such scenarios.

Comment: The data isn't valid CSV - "for deployment """@related activities" - doesn't make any sense.  You need the quotes to handle the field with the <CR> in it.  So you need the CSV option due to the embedded <CR> but the quoting is invalid per the spec.  The organization producing the file refusing to fix their bug.  The first thing I'd do is bring the field I entered above and ask the file provider what data, exactly, needs to be in the RS table.  My bet is that this was supposed to be 4 double quotes, not 3, which would be 2 embedded double quotes in the table field.